# Disable payment failed email in Magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento1.9.3

[image]

I want to know how to disable the payment failed email,
which is sent to admin if payment fails in Magento 1 from back-end or using code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting to disable it from the admin.

This email is sent when the method `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php:sendPaymentFailedEmail` is called.

If you search the term `sendPaymentFailedEmail` in source code, you will see that this method is called in `Mage_Checkout_MultishippingController`, `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`, `Mage_XmlConnect_CheckoutController` and `Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract`.

So, I see at least 2 options :

1) If you want to disable this email only for one type of action (for example ine the onepage), you should rewrite the controller you want and delete the `sendPaymentFailedEmail` call.

2) If you want to disable this email globally, you should rewrite the helper `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php` with something like :

```
public function sendPaymentFailedEmail($checkout, $message, $checkoutType = 'onepage')
{
    return $this;
}
```